# Spoofed 127.0.0.0/8 possible?

Tags: ipv4, security

If packets with ip source and/or ip destination 127.0.0.0/8 leaves the node, what can possibly happen? Can this be used as an attack vector against control plane (assuming L2 connectivity)?

Scenarios:

1. destination is a control plane service on a loopback address (possibly bypassing ACLs depending on the architecture?)
2. responses to a local service (reflection because of a 127.0.0.0/8 source IP)
   etc.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 3):

Two cases here:

127.0.0.0/8 as a source address, real IP as destinantion:

- might reach the target (if reverse path filtering is disabled on routers), but replies will "go out" the loopback interface (actually stay inside)
- since no replies, only unidirectional attacks possible - protocols such as TCP wont work, because handshake is needed

127.0.0.0/8 as a destination address (manually crafted packet, with the targets MAC address in the header)

- might be accepted by the target if forwarding is enabled
- wont traverse any routers, since routers forward 127.0.0.0/8 packets to their internal loopbacks

Either way, in most cases, these (and simmilar) packets are filtered on firewalls:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogon_filtering
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martian_packet
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_path_forwarding#Unicast_RPF_.28uRPF.29 ("*packets with source addresses that could not be reached via the input interface can be dropped without disruption to normal use, as they are probably from a misconfigured or malicious source*.")

Comment: 127.0.0.0/8 as source, some services (such as NTP, https://www.team-cymru.org/ReadingRoom/Templates/secure-ntp-template.html) with access restricted to ip.src==127.0.0.1, then the packet might get processed, and result in reflection/amplification attack on a local service that isn't normally accessible from outside?

Comment: Could be, but every reply packet, would "stay within" the loopback interface.

Comment: Good answer.  Might want to add that there used to be an attack where you sent packet to a destination using the destination's IP as the source.  It would cause the target to respond to itself, and in some iterations, create a reply/RST loop that would eventually crash the system.  This was called a [LAND or LAN-D attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAND).  Sending a spoofed packet with a source of 127.0.0.0/8 might be a similar attack vector.